# Away3D (4.x broomstick) How do you convert global to local position of an object?

Tags: actionscript-3, 3d, away3d

I am building a game that launches a ball at a target(Plane). The Plane is rotated back 45 degrees. I want to convert the global ball position(x,y,z) into the local coords of the target so I can detect where it hits.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the target plane's `inverseSceneTransform` to transform the `position` vector of the ball. That should do it.

```
var localPosition : Vector3D;
localPosition = plane.inverseSceneTransform.transformVector( ball.position );
```

That should give you the ball's position in the plane's local space.

Comment: Thanks so much! Are you one of the developers on away3D? I think I have seen your name before on the away3D forums.

Answer (score 2):

Above solution only works if the item/ball is directly on the stage. If it isnt, you should use ball.scenePosition!

```
item.position = targetContainer.inverseSceneTransform.transformVector(item.scenePosition);
```

Comment: Developing witch away3D is extremely tedious, since not even the official answers from their developers are 100% useable!

If I had to start the project anew, I'd force my boss to buy Flare3d instead of using Away3D. It isn't saving if a free library costs you double the development time in the long run.